# C ternary : do two distinct things

Tags: c, ternary

I was asking myself if its was possible to do something like that :

```
condition ? do this && THIS : else;
```

like :

```
nb = (nb1 + nb2) > 9 ? (nb1 + nb2) % 10 && nb1 + 1 : 0;
```

Note this is just an example, it means nothing.

Comment: `(nb1 + nb2) % 10 && nb1 + 1` is a single expression, not "two distinct things".

Comment: If you need to do two things that really are separate, then you should consider using a normal `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way:

```
condition ? function_that_does_several_things() : else_expr;
```

The other thing is you can collect expressions in a list:

```
int a = (1,2);
```

assigns `2` to `a`. So you can try this:

```
condition ? (do_this, and_this) : else_expr;
```

But I suggest against it; it's really hard to see what is going on here and a lot of people will be confused, surprise and frustrated when they see such code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not "do this", it's "evaluate this".  Remove the condition and the "false" path, and you get this:

```
 nb = (nb1 + nb2) % 10 && nb1 + 1;
```

So, yes, you can do it, but the value of `nb` will be the result of a logical expression ... which is essentially this:

```
 nb = ((nb1 + nb2) % 10 != 0) && (nb1 + 1 != 0);
```